# C# connection to oracle db using jdbc url

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to test a connection on a oracle db using a C# console application with a provided jdbc url from our dba. I have this basic code written.

```
using System;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace TestDBConnection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string conn = "User Id=myuserid;Password=mypassword;Data source=(CONNECT_DATA=(CUSTOM_JDBC_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://mypath:636/emomod1_app,cn=oraclecontext,dc=safeway,dc=com))";
        OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = conn;
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Connection to Oracle Atlas DB");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection to Oracle DB Successful!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection to Oracle DB Failed");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

But its failing with error

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12533: TNS:illegal ADDRESS parameters
```

What/How is the correct way of using jdbc url as a db connection string? Thanks.

Comment: You can't use jdbc connection string syntax with .NET. You need to use the .NET connection string syntax for Oracle. See:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: You can't - `jdbc` is for java. For .Net you need to use a different connection string - and the best place to learn what it should be is https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/